# How to input without change focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

Building an editor like below-- I need the user to be able to select some text but then use the input to do something without losing the selection.

```js
function doReplace(){
  const s = document.getSelection()
  if(s?.anchorNode.parentElement.id != "out")return;
  
  console.log('replace')
  out.innerText = out.innerText.substring(0,s.anchorOffset)+(inp.value||'FALLBACK')+out.innerText.substring(s.extentOffset)
  
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" placeholder="replace selection to" >
<button onclick="doReplace()">replace</button>
<p id="out">select some here and replace</p>
```

This demo reproduces the issue: one cannot use the input without losing their text selection.

How to input without changing focus?

A real world use case would be something like setting the font-size for the selection.

[image]

**EDIT**

Maybe cache selection is the way to go, but will loosing visual indication, trying to restore selection will lost focus again.

```js
let s

function doReplace() {
  if (s?.anchorNode?.parentElement.id != "out") return;

  console.log('replace')
  out.innerText = out.innerText.substring(0, s.anchorOffset) + (inp.value || 'FALLBACK') + out.innerText.substring(s.extentOffset)

}

function doRestore() {
  if (s?.anchorNode?.parentElement.id != "out") return;
  const sel = document.getSelection();
  sel.setBaseAndExtent(s.anchorNode, s.anchorOffset, s.anchorNode, s.extentOffset);
}
out.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  const sel = document.getSelection()
  if(!sel)return;
  const {
    anchorNode,
    anchorOffset,
    extentOffset
  } = sel || {}
  s = {
    text: sel.toString(),
    anchorNode,
    anchorOffset,
    extentOffset
  }
  console.log(`sel`, s.anchorOffset, s.extentOffset, s.text)
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="inp" placeholder="replace selection to" autocomplete="false" onfocus="doRestore()">
<button onclick="doReplace()">replace</button>
<p id="out">select some here and replace</p>
```

Comment: _"How to input without changing focus?"_ - I don't see how that would be possible. You will have to _get_ the current selection,  before the focus change happens.

Comment: @CBroe - it might be possible if you were always listening for-- and caching-- any selection made by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see a way of this being possible. the input/textarea tags require focus so the user will be able to type.

I recommend you use an EventListener instead of an input tag:

```js
function doReplace(){
  const s = document.getSelection()
  if(s?.anchorNode.parentElement.id != "out")return;
  
  console.log('replace')
  out.innerText = out.innerText.substring(0,s.anchorOffset)+(inp.value||'FALLBACK')+out.innerText.substring(s.extentOffset)
  
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML += event.key 
});
```

```html
<div id="field"></div>
<button onclick="doReplace()">replace</button>
<p id="out">select some here and replace</p>
```